# How to verify that Windows Update is giving me all updates it should

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

It's been a long time since I last got an update through Windows Update. How can I determine whether or not Windows Update is working and giving me all updates it should?

Comment: In Windows 10, updates are cumulative, which means they include all older updates. If you have installed the latest cumulative Update, you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings`, then `Update & Security`, then `Advanced options`, and finally `View your update history`. As of today (12/7/15) the tip update should be KB3116908.

Comment: How do you know that the latest update should be KB3116908?

Comment: Doing what you describes only shows which updates I have. It does not tell me if Update is working properly.

Comment: @JarleHammenKnudsen I know what the latest update is because I checked. What do you mean by "working properly" if not that you have all the updates you should have?

Comment: How and where did you check?

Comment: I have access to machines that are specifically kept on the very latest patches for compatibility testing purposes by competent personnel. I just checked what updates they had. You could also just check the knowledge base or any machine you have good reason to believe is current.

Comment: Where is the knowledge base and specifically information on available updates?

Comment: @JarleHammenKnudsen With IE, you can go to [the Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com).